# thymeleaf error message with converted special characters

Tags: html, spring-boot, utf-8, thymeleaf, properties-file

for my web app (spring boot  + thymeleaf) i use message_fr.properties file witch contains some special characters converted to html 
the problem comes when i display the error validation message in `lang=fr` :

```
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}"></span>
```

assume that key/value are : `NotEmpty.item.title = Ne doit pas &ecirc;tre null`
on screen it displays the error message without conversion : `Ne doit pas &ecirc;tre null`

how can i resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`th:errors` will escape HTML in the same way that `th:text` does. Before 3.0.8, you would have to iterate over the errors like this:

```
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('title')}"></span>
```

However, post 3.0.8, Thymeleaf-Spring includes `th:uerrors` for unescaped error messages to the same effect:

```
<span th:uerrors="*{title}"></span>
```